# c# entity framework track dirty on entity not added to context yet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I suppose the question is simple enough.  I am doing something where I am creating the entity and then not immediately adding it to the context meaning its officially not going to be tracked for changes.

Example:

Create entity:
`var g = new Foo(){id = 1, description =  "Object1"}`
(Upon creation this object does not trigger any changed or dirty flags)

Change property:
`g.description = "Object2";`
(At this point I would like for something to say it is dirty)

The one thing i can think of would be to somehow create the object then add it to the context, but then immediately roll back the contexts tracking of the fact that an object was just added and then any further changes to that object would trigger the `Context.changeTracker.HasChanges()` to trigger.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Either use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and create a `OnPropertyChanged` function that executes the event and also remmembers all the changed properties in a list.

Or you could use something more complex like AOP.
An example of that is to use Castle's Dynamic Proxy: http://www.christophdebaene.com/blog/2009/01/10/aop-in-action-part-2-dirty-tracking-using-mixins-with-castles-dynamicproxy/